# Use Kinect in ROS Jade

Tags: kinect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

HI,
I am Beginner in ROS and I want to use XboX Kinect with  ROS (jade). But, I don't find any tutorials about using kinect in ROS Jade.

Any one know about this, please help me?

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and ROS jade.
Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/212578/use-kinect-in-ros-jade/) by [SalahUddin](https://answers.ros.org/users/22958/salahuddin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2015-06-30

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey, Im also a beginner in ROS and using the same jade version on Ubuntu 14.04. depending on ur application, u may use ViSP or Point Cloud Library . search for software packages

---

Originally posted by [xhuv](https://answers.ros.org/users/23094/xhuv/) with karma: 26 on 2015-07-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0